# Inserting AutoText as a row in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to create an "Add Row" button in an MS Word 2016 form that will add another row to the bottom of a table that contains text content controls.

Simply adding a row doesn't include the content controls and copying a previous row will also copy over any text that has been added to those content controls, neither of which I want.

I read somewhere that it is possible to save an unpopulated row as AutoText, then insert the AutoText as a new row. I just am unable to find how to do this. I have the unpopulated row saved as AutoText, I just don't know how to add it to the bottom of the table using VBA.

Also, the form will be edit protected. The VBA code needed to unlock the form then relock it I already have. I am just leaving it off for right now while I attempt to figure this out.

I tried the below code, but keep getting a type mismatch error.

```
Private Sub AddInmate_Click()

ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Select
NormalTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Inmate_Row").Insert _
    Where:=ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Range.Rows.Last

End Sub
```

Any help you all can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempt is very close - it's trying to insert the new row "on top of" or "in" the last row. The trick is to get the table's `Range` then collapse it so that the target insertion point is immediately after the table. When table rows are pasted/inserted immediately after an existing table, inside the same paragraph mark, Word auotomatically incorporates them in the existing table.

```
Private Sub AddInmate_Click()
    Dim tmpl As Word.Template
    Dim rngTbl As Word.Range

    Set rngTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Range
    rngTbl.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Set tmpl = NormalTemplate
    tmpl.BuildingBlockEntries("Inmate_Row").Insert _
        Where:=rngTbl, RichText:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd take is to use code like:

```
 With Selection.Tables(1).Rows
    'Insert an empty paragraph after our table, then replace it with a replica of the last row
    With .Last.Range
      .Next.InsertBefore vbCr
      .Next.FormattedText = .FormattedText
    End With
    'Reset all content controls in the new last row
    For Each CCtrl In .Last.Range.ContentControls
      With CCtrl
        If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then .Checked = False
        If .Type = wdContentControlRichText Or .Type = wdContentControlText Then .Range.Text = ""
        If .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList Then .DropdownListEntries(1).Select
        If .Type = wdContentControlComboBox Then .DropdownListEntries(1).Select
        If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then .Range.Text = ""
      End With
    Next
  End With
```

For a complete ContentControlOnExit macro implementing this in a situation analogous to yours, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989